# color scheme setup for iTerm

Tags: osx, editors, iterm

How do you setup color scheme of iTerm on Mac? For color scheme, I mean using different color to display folder name, file name, machine name, etc.

Comment: If anyone have good solutions, it will be great. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use oh-my-zsh, with the [ys theme](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes#ys) and it does what I need.